# How to create a keyboard that sticks to the view during transition like in Snapchat?

Tags: swift, uikeyboard, uiviewanimationtransition

In Snapchat and also FB Messenger the keyboard is not automatically dismissed but sticks to the old VC during transition. I'm using a PageViewController and would like to have the keyboard stay open when the user transitions to new VC.

[Here's a sample project](https://github.com/petard/keyboardTransition) that illustrates the default behaviour: the keyboard is dismissed and protrudes into the new VC during transition. Ideally the keyboard is not dismissed and stays within the view of the first VC.

[image]

Default Apple transition:

[image]

Comment: please include some code?

Comment: @RachelHarvey not sure which code you mean, currently i have no idea how implement such a keyboard behaviour.

Comment: Oh, you said you were using a PageViewController, so I assumed you had tried some things out. Try putting a textview in one of the pages to see how the keyboard behaves I guess?

Comment: I see, in my PageViewController one VC has a textfield, the second some UILabels. By default, the keyboard will be dismissed when user changes VCs. Also it overlaps to the second VC during transition. I updated the post with a sample project.